# How to pass a default params or state to the react router? any alternative approach?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-router

I have a state that is list of valid name (valid_list = []). I want to route to home page if someone types a /topics/:name which is not valid. I want o hence pass the valid list to the new component.

**I have mentioned all my attempts at the end.**

My parent component is this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom'

import Topic from '../topic'

class App extends Component { {

  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <Route path="/topics/:name" component={Topic} />
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

the calling component is

```
import React,{ Component } from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom' 

class Maintopic extends Component { {
 render() {
    return (
<div>
    <Link to='/topic:$name' > NextTopic </Link>
</div>
  );
}
```

and called component is something where I am facing issues.

```
render() {

    return (
         <div>
             <h1>{this.props.match.params.name}</h1>
        </div>

      );
    }
```

---

**Attempt 1:**

Passing object to link:

```
<Link to={
           {
              pathname:`/topic/${name}`,
              state:{
                      valid_list : this.state.valid_list
                   }
          }}>
```

And then performing check on the called component by using artlist this.props.location.state.valid_list,

*Here the problem is if I manually type URL like "/topic/name1" or "/topic/name2" i get error like "TypeError: Cannot read property 'valid_list' of undefined"*

**Attempt 2:**

Having called and calling component both have manually stored state in their component

*Here issues is I really want my valid_list to be dynamic and can be increased visa input button in future implementation. Plus it does not make sense to maintain different copies of same data.*

Comment: the valid_list is an array ? that items that need to be inside the array is provided for you in a static way ? o should be dynamically ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `valid_list` is an array of stuff, one solution for your problem is making a decorator and decorates your component, so you should do it like this.

```
const withValidList = (valid_list) => (Component) => (routerProps) => {
  return <Component {...routerProps} valid_list={valid_list} />
}
```

then in your `<Route>` you must decorate your component with the `valid_list` like this

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom'

import Topic from '../topic'

class App extends Component { {

  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <Route path="/topics/:name" component={withValidList(['list1', 'list2'])(Topic)} />
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

that's should works, so basically your are wrapping your component adding some extra functionality with the decorator pattern, that give you the ability to passing down the `valid_list` props to be used into the `Topic` component.

Comment: so my array is dynamic and constantly getting updated. I am using forms to allow user to change this data

Comment: @AshishKumar the solution provided still working, because your probably get valid_list updated each time the component is mounted, so each time the valid_list array will pass down to the target component in this case the Topic component, is that right ?